# Как спарсить данные с файла Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл list.txt

```
admin  7777
root    toor
anonymous anonymous 
big  off
```

Проблема в том что пробелы между ними везде разные...

```
from re import sub

with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(sub(' ', '', line.strip()))

=> admin12345
   roottoor
   anonymousanonymous
   bigoff
```

Можно ли как то записать admin12345 в переменные login и password или же словарь?

```
login = 'admin'
password = '12345'
# и так далее по циклу...
```

Comment: То есть разделить на одинаковое кол-во символов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in file.readlines():
        first, second = line.split()
```

В `first` первое слово, в `second` - второе. Дальше делайте что хотите.

Или можно

```
for line in file.readlines():
        words = line.split()
```

Тогда в `words` будет список из слов строки.

```
['admin', '7777']
['root', 'toor']
['anonymous', 'anonymous']
['big', 'off']
```